# Laravel 4 rest api non-implicit action routing and left join

Tags: rest, laravel, laravel-4, left-join, eloquent

I am pretty new to Laravel but I certainly like Laravel 4. I am stuck at two points -

- The first is that - I have a non crud action method in a controller that has to do a left join with two tables and return the result. There are two tables, Employees and Departments. I am trying to get all assigned and non-assigned employees for creating an association between them. This action method is inside "EmployeeController". It is named as "allAssignedEmployees". I tried the following routing but seems it doesn't work :

  `Route::resource('employees/assignedEmployees/{deptId}', 'EmployeesController@assignedEmployees');`
- Secondly, I am not kind of too sure about my left join. The following is what I made out of googling

  ```
         $unassignedEmployees = DB::table('employee')
          ->join('department', function($join)
          {
              $join->on('department.employee_id', '=', 'employee.id');
          })
          ->where('department.id', '=', $deptId)
          ->get();
  ```

  Apparently what I wanted in SQL is  - `select * from employee emp left join department dept on dept.employee_id = employee.id and employee.dept_id = 2`

  The other related questions unanswered I had in mind are - how to log in Laravel 4? Especially SQL queries or general log statements. Is there an inbuilt logging support.

  I know its a lot of questions, but I am sure the answers will help my learning process hence thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First I'm not being rude but you should have studied Documentation First at least.

Now coming to your questions:

About Resource Controller:
`Route::resource('employees', 'EmployeesController');`

This single route declaration creates multiple routes to handle a variety of RESTful actions on the employees resource. Likewise, the generated controller will already have stubbed methods for each of these actions with notes informing you which URIs and verbs they handle.

Actions Handled By Resource Controller

```
Verb        Path                  Action        Route Name

GET         /employees            index         employees.index
GET         /employees/create     create        employees.create
POST        /employees            store         employees.store
GET         /employees/{id}       show          employees.show
GET         /employees/{id}/edit  edit          employees.edit
PUT/PATCH   /employees/{id}       update        employees.update
DELETE      /employees/{id}       destroy       employees.destroy
```

So if you have created resource controller then get routes like employees/{id} will be handled by controllers show method.
But if you want specific method to handle then you have to route it like this
`Route::get('employees/assignedEmployees/{deptId}',''EmployeesController@assignedEmployees'');`

And regarding logging read [here](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#logging)

Comment: Thanks for the response :) I did read the documentation..by non-crud I meant specific action methods that involve special type of querying as in above case a left join etc...I am sorry that I should have been more clear on what I meant by non-crud(probably non-implicit actions like the ones in documentation)

Comment: is your problem solved or not?if not what exactly your problem is?

Comment: Hi Rahul, the routing and logging problem is solved but the Left join problem is still there :( The query above doesn't return anything....I am unable to log the query nor debug further...Kinda stuck there :( Thanks for lending a helping hand...

Comment: `DB::table('employee')
        ->leftJoin('department', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('department.employee_id', '=', 'employee.id')
            ->on('department.id', '=', $deptId);
        })
        ->get();` try this one